# Firefox print css blank

Tags: css, firefox, print-preview

One particular page on my website is coming up completely blank in Firefox Print Preview. It has 3 pages but they are all blank.

IE and Chrome both show the print preview just fine.

If I use the firefox developer toolbar `media emulate print` this will show the print css as expected. It is only blank in the actual print preview.

Resetting my firefox print settings made no difference.

Does anyone know how I can diagnose this? or know of anything that might cause such an issue?

Comment: If you are using windows. Do a reboot. This happens with FF sometimes on Windows machines. Funny bug. All else fails read mozilla documentation: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-printing-problems-firefox

Comment: @Adrianopolis Have already restarted several times since finding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding `display:block;` to my main header/content/footer sections which I am using as `display:table-row;`

This works but is strange because it wasn't a problem on any other page on the site even though they use the same main layout.